# Displaying daily events in a calendar

Tags: php, html, css, calendar

I'm working on a calendar web application in PHP and I need help displaying the events for a day.

What I'm doing at the moment is looping through each hour of the day (from 0 to 23) and then display any events that start at that time. The events have both a startingTime and endingTime, stored as INT (timestamps) in the database.

On the left part of the calendar, I display the 23 hours, and on the right part, I want to display boxes (one per event) placed at the right place (so that it lines up with the starting hour) and with a height depending on its duration.

Currently, I display the hours as 120px high `div`'s, and I make it so that each 15 minutes of duration corresponds to 30 pixels. This is working as expected. To handle the relative position of the events, I place them in `position: absolute`  in a `position: relative` container, and I set the `top` property depending on the start hour.

Here's the code that I'm using to do that :

```
//Get the starting hour
$startingHour = date("H", $event->startingTime);

//Get the duration
$duration = $event->endingTime - $event->startingTime;
$duration = ceil($duration / 60); //We want minutes

//Get the multiplier for the height
$height = ($duration / 15) * 30; //30 pixels per 15 minutes                     

//Get the offset from the top, depending on the starting hour
$topOffset = $startingHour * 120;           

$style = 'style="height: ' . $height . 'px; top: ' . $topOffset . 'px;"';
```

I then `echo`  the `$style` variable later on, when I'm making my `div` for the event.

This is working as expected, *but it doesn't feel right*. What if I change the design later on, and each block is now 35 pixels? I have to change my code at a variety of places to make sure that it still lines up.

I tried using tables, which seemed more appropriate for something like that, but it's even more confusing when I want certain events to last more than an hour. For instance, a 1h45 event starting at 3h00 would fill the entire 3h00 block, and 3/4 of the 4h00 block.

**TL : DR** I'm trying to find the best way to display events as box that have a relative height and position, depending on their duration and starting hour. What is the best way to do this in order to keep the code easy to maintain, and not the big spaghetti mess that it is right now?

Here is an image of what I want to achieve - basically what the code posted above outputs. I want a similar output, but in a more semantic and appropriate way.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason why you are not using data attributes or CSS classes on your divs? I would not use inline styles, because like you say: if the design needs to be changed, you would have to alter your php code. Always try to abstract your presentational logic from the application's logic.

From my point of view you have two options here:
Option1: Use data-attributes on divs and use the attribute's values to calculate their corresponding position and height with javascript. So I would append data attributes to the divs like f.e. data="sh1030-eh1330". Then I would use javascript to read the starting hour and end hour values, calculate the height and position the div. You could choose between percentage or pixels.
Option 2: append a css class name for the height and for the vertical position of the div. F.e.  class="timeslot drtu7 sh1330"
Then write enough css classes for all possible values. F.e. .drtu7{height:175px}  .sh1230 {top: 600px}
This implies you'd need to write quite a few css rules, BUT also only have to alter css code when the design needs to change, because you would be able to reuse the "duration unit" (in this example 1 "duration unit" is 1 quarter of an hour and 25px in height) and the "starting hour" css class to redefine the height an position of the "timeslot" divs.

Comment: I suppose that the reason I'm using inline styling at the moment and not classes/data-attributes is because I didn't think of using Javascript for this, and I didn't want to end up with a million classes to set in the CSS. Data-attributes sounds like a great idea, I'll give that a shot and see how it goes. Although, what I would like is to move away from that structure of absolute positionning which just doesn't seem right.

Comment: Tons of CSS classes is not so bad. You could try to consider SASS for generating this CSS. If you don't want to work with CSS classes or get stuck with positioning, I would go for a calendar Javascript plugin which you could feed with date objects... There's plenty of them. I have worked on several responsive web projects and used calendars like  [CLNDR](http://kylestetz.github.io/CLNDR/) and [eventCalendar](http://www.vissit.com/jquery-event-calendar-plugin-english-version/) . Very useful and slick calendars!